# I hit the rate limit for twitteR even from the first request

Tags: r, twitter, limit, blocking, rate

As I say in the title, I always hit the rate limit (supposedly) even from the first request. Therefore, I cannot download anything from twitter.

Here is my example code in R:

```
tweets = searchTwitter('blabla', n=1, cainfo = "cacert.pem")
```

And I keep getting this message:

```
[1] "Too Many Requests"
[1] "Rate limited .... blocking for a minute ..."
```

What could I try?

---

```
reqURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
consumerKey <- "KEY"
consumerSecret <- "KEY"
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=reqURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL,
                         authURL=authURL)
twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
tweets = searchTwitter('blabla', n=10, cainfo = "cacert.pem")
```

The code is the above. Without any apparent reason, I managed to download some tweets but sometimes I still keep getting this message.

Moreover, I'm searchong for a string and I cannot find it although I'm 100% sure that it exists on twitter. I'm getting a message that no response was retrieved from the server.

Comment: Can you post all your example code (including how you connect to the twitter API). This is probably not related to a specific R issue, but it may help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Are you using the version on CRAN or the dev version on my site? The latter fixed a handful of bugs that could be at play here.

Comment: Since I'm new to R, I don't quite understand what you mean. I'm using the version from CRAN (I think). How could I use the latter?

Comment: You can either get at them via github (user geoffjentry) or I sometimes bundle them up & post the URL to the mailing list, e.g.: http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2013-March/000231.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, too. But I think the reason is that the new Twitter API sets its "rate limits" to only allow 15 calls in 15 minutes.

Therefore, if you exceed the rate limitation, your account will be blocked for a while...
But you'll be able to access the data after another 15 mins.
(It works for me! You may try.)

For your reference: http://www.tweetings.net/site/2012/10/rate-limits-and-the-new-twitter-api/